# Is it impossible to load a javascript library in a Google colab cell?

Tags: javascript, google-colaboratory

I have Python code that creates HTML to visualize a Python object using the `_repr_html` method. This means I can show the object by simply putting `display(obj)` in my cell or even just placing `obj` as the last statement in my cell.

That HTML loads javascript libraries from the Internet, e.g. the jquery library like so:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

However when such a script tag is part of HTML I try to visualize in Colab, it gets completely removed!
For example, the following code in a cell produces output which does not contain the script element any more:

```
HTML("""
<div id="containing"
<div id="div1">
  some text
</div>  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</div>
""")
```

The alternative would be to include the verbatim javascript code in every cell (`<script type="text/javascript>..actual javascript ...<script>`), which works, but seems like an unnecessary overhead.

Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
from IPython.display import HTML, Javascript, display
from google.colab import output

display(HTML("""
<div id="div1">
  some text
</div>  
"""))

display(Javascript(url="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"))

output.eval_js('''
 $("#div1").append("<p>Hello, JQuery</p>");
''');
```

A full notebook with this example is:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xnfhiVsm6u_TkSoni0WaGydigOCPj5Mw