# Setting Javascript Global Variables in Colab Notebook

Tags: javascript, jupyter-notebook, global-variables, google-colaboratory

I am looking at how to load an external JS URL in a Google Colab notebook once and have it be available in all subsequent cells.

It seems that Google Colab uses a different worker thread or other isolation for each notebook cell.  This means that doing something like the solution found in [Is it impossible to load a javascript library in a Google colab cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67025161/is-it-impossible-to-load-a-javascript-library-in-a-google-colab-cell) to load external libraries in one cell works for that cell:

```
from IPython.display import display, Javascript
display(Javascript(url="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"))
display(Javascript('''console.log($);'''))
```

but move to the next cell and run:

```
display(Javascript('''console.log($);'''))
```

and console will report `undefined variable: $`.

I have tried setting the variable in `Window` and `globalThis` to no avail.  Anyone have success?

(The library I need is not JQuery.  Just using it as an example)